# Tricky Rails 5 ActiveRecord "where" query involving multiple associated models and an "or" operator

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a PurchaseOrder model with a has_many relationship to a Line Item model.  Both the PurchaseOrder and Line Item models have a has_many relationship to a Delivery model.  The Delivery model has an "expected_arrival" attribute.  I need to fetch all the Purchase Orders where either of the following conditions are true:

a) the order's delivery has an "expected_arrival" attribute of yesterday or earlier
b) any of the order's line items have deliveries with an "expected_arrival" attribute of yesterday or earlier

I had planned to use the Rails 5 `or` operator, but apparently there is a known bug in Rails when combining `or` with `joins` or `includes`:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24055

I then tried using `group` and `having`, like so:

```
PurchaseOrder.left_joins(:deliveries, {line_items: :deliveries})
  .group("purchase_orders.id")
  .having("MAX(line_items.deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ? 
    OR MAX(deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ?", 
  Time.now, 
  Time.now)`
```

This produced the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "deliveries"
```

LINE 1: ..." IS NULL GROUP BY purchase_orders.id HAVING (MAX(line_items...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "deliveries", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
`

It's strange that Rails is telling me I can't access the deliveries table in this way, because each of the following queries works by themselves:

```
PurchaseOrder.left_joins(:deliveries).group("purchase_orders.id").having("MAX(deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ?", Time.now)`

PurchaseOrder.left_joins({line_items: :deliveries}).group("purchase_orders.id").having("MAX(deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ?", Time.now)`
```

I would like to avoid making to database calls, which is why I originally wanted to use the `or` query.  As you can see, in both of the last two queries, I'm simply referencing `deliveries.expected_arrival` instead of `line_items.deliveries.expected_arrival`.  I'm assuming this is where Rails has a problem, and it implies I need to alias `line_items.deliveries` somehow.

Is that a correct assumption?  If so, how would I go about that?  And if not, what's the correct way to structure this query?

Comment: Would something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4795633/8088139) help

Comment: I'd much prefer a Rails command vs vanilla SQL.

Comment: is the `Delivery` model have a polymorphic association with `PurchaseOrder`/`LineItem` or does it have a foreign key for each?

Comment: @MichaelGorman there is a many-to-many relationship (i.e. join tables) between Deliveries and PurchaseOrders, and between Deliveries and LineItems.

Comment: that makes it a bit stickier but still doable.  I'll update my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell Rails does not have a built in joins method capable of multiple joins to the same table, but sql does.  From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4795633/8088139) we see that it can be done by adding a parameter to the joins statement to name the joins.

```
SELECT i.name as name, v1.value as value_1, v2.value as value_2 
  FROM item i
       INNER JOIN item_value iv ON iv.item = i.id
       INNER JOIN property p ON iv.property = p.id
       LEFT JOIN value v1 ON p.name = 'prop1' AND v1.id = iv.value
       LEFT JOIn value v2 ON p.name = 'prop2' AND v2.id = iv.value
```

Rails does allow you to put sql as part of the joins statement as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39674948/8088139)

for this use case

```
PurchaseOrder
  .joins("LEFT JOIN deliveries_purchase_orders on purchase_orders.id = deliveries_purchase_orders.purchase_order_id)
  .joins("LEFT JOIN deliveries order_deliveries ON deliveries.id = deliveries_purchase_orders.delivery_id")
  .left_joins(:line_items)
  .joins("LEFT JOIN deliveries_line_items on line_items.id = deliveries_line_items.line_item_id)
  .joins("LEFT JOIN deliveries item_deliveries ON deliveries.id = deliveries_line_items.delivery_id")
  .group("purchase_orders.id")
  .having("MAX(item_deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ? 
    OR MAX(order_deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ?", 
  Time.now, 
  Time.now)`
```

Not as clean as it could be if there was a railsy way to do it, but it should get you moving forward.

EDIT:

This was all written in PostgreSQL and the formatting would be slightly different for other flavors of SQL

Alternate Solution.

Since this request is doing 5 joins requests it may be preferable to add a field to the `PurchaseOrder` and `LineItem` for Latest Expected Delivery Date, and use Rails after create/update filters to maintain them.  Taking the processing load off of the read, and onto the write.

Comment: Were the `AS` statements missing intentionally or by accident?  I tried both your exact code (missing some closing quotes btw) and the following (https://pastebin.com/V8rQ9SNj) but I keep getting errors like the following:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "deliveries_purchase_orders"
LINE 1: ...ries AS order_deliveries ON order_deliveries.id = deliveries...`

Comment: well that looks like it may just be that the joins table name isn't `deliveries_purchase_orders`.   What are the joins tables named?

Comment: Looks like the join table name was part of the problem.  I got to the following statement, which works:

`PurchaseOrder.joins("LEFT JOIN delivery_purchase_orders on purchase_orders.id = delivery_purchase_orders.purchase_order_id").joins("LEFT JOIN deliveries AS order_deliveries ON order_deliveries.id = delivery_purchase_orders.delivery_id").left_joins(:line_items)`

But it fails when I concatenate the following:

`.joins("LEFT JOIN delivery_line_items on line_items.id = delivery_line_items.line_item_id")`

Comment: The error is: 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "line_items"
LINE 1: ...ders.delivery_id LEFT JOIN delivery_line_items on line_items...
                                                             ^
` (note the upward arrow is pointing at `line_items` at the end there).  I'm guessing the problem is caused by the `left_joins(:line_items)`.

Comment: can you see the complete sql being generated in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try that.

```
PurchaseOrder.includes(:deliveries, line_items: :deliveries)
  .group("purchase_orders.id")
  .where("MAX(line_items.deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ? 
    OR MAX(deliveries.expected_arrival) <= ?", 
  Time.now, 
  Time.now)
```

Comment: Isn't this almost exactly what I posted in my initial question?  The only difference appears to be `includes` vs. `left_joins`.